# Can't write to a text file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime

I'm trying to write to a txt file in a folder in my project but i can't it throws an exception for some reason i have tried everything and it still wont work

```
// settings
    // same as (ms-appx:///MyFolder/MyFile.txt)
    var _Folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    _Folder = await _Folder.GetFolderAsync("MyFolder");

    // acquire file
    var _File = await _Folder.GetFileAsync("MyFile.txt");
    Assert.IsNotNull(_File, "Acquire File");

    // write content
    var _WriteThis = "Hello World";
    //  Error here
    await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(_File, _WriteThis);
```

Here is the code that i have i been using the error happens when i want to write to the file

Here is the exception

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024891
  Message=Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at ManipulatingTxtFiles.MainPage.<addBtn_Click>d__a.MoveNext() in c:\Users\Tunde\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ManipulatingTxtFiles\ManipulatingTxtFiles\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 115
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__0(Object state)
       at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.<InvokeCore>b__0(Object o)
       at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
       at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
       at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Can you post the exception message and stacktrace?

Comment: Why aren't you just using a [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamwriter) object?

Answer (score 3):

Your package folder and all its contents (i.e. anything referenced from Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation, ms-appx:///, or ms-appx-web:/// is read-only. Hence the access denied exception.

Use your Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.LocalFolder or TemporaryFolder instead (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.applicationdata.aspx), which can also be done using ms-appdata:///local/ or ms-appdata:///temp/. These locations are read-write.

Comment: So your not able to edit or read files that are directly in your solution

Comment: You can read, but not write. In short, you cannot modify the app package as the user downloaded from the Store, which is important for security reasons among other things.